# Can you start the default music player in the background?

Tags: android, android-intent, media-player, android-service

I have 2 areas in my app that launch the default media player on the device and play an audio file (a podcast).  One gets it from the file system after a download, the other streams it from the file on the site.

This is working fine right now, problem is if I hit back or home to try and get back to my app after it launches the media player, the player closes and the playback stops.

Is there a way to launch it in the background or as a service so that when I go back to the app, the music keeps playing in the player.  I want it to function as if you started a song from the music player.  So the user can use the device as normal and the playback will continue.

Here's my code for launching the music player for streaming.

```
private void playPodcast( Podcast podcast ) {
    Intent intent = new Intent( Intent.ACTION_VIEW );
    intent.setDataAndType( Uri.parse( podcast.getContentLink() ), "audio/*" );
    startActivity( intent );
}
```

Thanks in advance.

---

**EDIT!**  After receiving the advice below, I tried launching it as a Service.  I've tried this in 2 ways.
Both ways have this as the manifest entry:

```
<service android:name=".DefaultMusicPlayerLaunchService">
</service>
```

The first attempt was to make a Service class which was merely a skeleton and launching it with a similar method as above.

DefaultMusicPlayerLaunchService V1:

```
public class DefaultMusicPlayerLaunchService extends Service {

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind( Intent intent ) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    public int onStartCommand( Intent intent, int flags, int startId ) {
        return START_STICKY;
    }
}
```

playPodcast Method:

```
    private void playPodcast( Podcast podcast ) {
        Intent intent = new Intent( getApplicationContext(), 
                                    DefaultMusicPlayerLaunchService.class );
        intent.setDataAndType( Uri.parse( podcast.getContentLink() ), "audio/*" );
        startService( intent );
    }
```

My thought was that this way, it would launch the music player similarly to the way it was in the Activity I had before, but launch it without leaving the screen it was on.  I didn't see anything happen in the LogCat.  I feel like this should work but I'm missing something.

The other method I attempted involved serializing the podcast object as an extra and putting it on the `Intent` I made for the `DefaultMusicPlayerLaunchService`.  Then, in the `onStartCommand` method, I grabbed the object, created a new `Intent` and then called `startActivity` similarly to how the original `playPodcast` method at the top does.  And as expected, it does just what the top one does... launches the player but as soon as I hit back or home, it closes.

I apologize if I'm missing something obvious.  I'm new to Android and everything I've worked with up to now have used `Activity`.  This is my first attempt at starting a `Service`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can start it as a service. You need to create a class that extends android.app.Service. And call startService(intent) from an Activity passing it an intent that will start the service. Override the onStartCommand method and have it return START_STICKY which will have the service run until its explicitly stopped. Either by you in code or by the Android OS to conserve resources. You can also override onBind to bind the service to an Activity which will give the service the same importance as a foreground Activity which makes it less likely that Android will kill the service to save resources.

Comment: Thanks for your input.  Sorry it took me so long to try this.  I'm not sure if I'm doing this right.  I've tried it 2 different ways and neither is working.  I'm going to update the main topic with more info.